# php setcookie synatx error when called with multiple parameters

Tags: php

For the simple program I keep getting syntax error on line 3 using setcookie function. If I comment out line 3 then the program works.

```
<?php
setcookie('my_cookie_1');
setcookie('my_cookie_2' , "say something");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <p style="width: 60%; text-align: center;">
          The cookies have been set.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error text I get is:

```
[28-May-2017 22:28:14 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"say something"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /.../gatnyarws.php on line 3
```

And yes I newbie to PHP and I have been programming in other languages for sometime and I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Please help,
John

Comment: @MateuszSip why this is duplicate that question?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.  Read it carefully, then read the documentation and make updates.

Comment: @user2182349, the PHP builtin function setcookie is defined to accept multiple parameters, yet when I try to use multiple parameters I get a syntax error.

Comment: FWIW, I copied it verbatim from the post, and it successfully set `my_cookie_2`.  Did you copy/paste from your code?

Comment: @TimMorton I did copy and paste my code into message. So I tried what you did, and when I copied the example back into my program it worked. Which means that I had a character problem I could not see. Thanks Tim.